# Sql CE, SQLite and XML

Tags: xml, database, relational-database, sql-server-ce

I am developing an application for personal use and I don't know which is more efficient way to store my data.
Ok, here is the case, My data structure includes 5-6 master detail tables. The application will be working locally. It will create database for each project separately, meaning that the user will create new project (xml file or database) and store new data in it. Originally I thought that it will be more suitable to create through application new databases per project. But now i thinking it will be more easy to have an xml file storage.  What do you think? Any example?